# export_graphviz extratreesclassifier python visualization

Tags: python-3.x, tree, expression-trees, graph-visualization

Is there a way to use export_graphviz to represent the final tree of extratreesclasiffier? If not, how can it be visually representented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way to visualize a specific tree from *sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier*.

But you can visualize it with a single tree from *sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier*.

```
from sklearn import tree
...

#Fit an Extra Tree model to the data
model = tree.ExtraTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Use http://webgraphviz.com to visualize the graph of this file
with open("tree_classifier.txt", "w") as f:
    f = tree.export_graphviz(model, out_file=f)
```

Here an example with Decision tree that also work with Extra tree:
http://dataaspirant.com/2017/04/21/visualize-decision-tree-python-graphviz/